# Using Global resource file without app_globalresources in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a MVC project where I need to use a string resource in 'WebResource.resx' file across multiple project present in a single solution.
That string value might change in future, that's why I have placed it in a resource.

I came to know that using 'app_globalresources' folder is not a good practice.

Is there any solution use that resource file in multiple project?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there aren't any specific 'good practices' for keeping resource files, they are just auto generated class files that allow for ease of localization based on the culture setting of a thread.

Simply create a project within your solution, a class library, create your RESX file in that project and reference that project within the other solutions that need access to the properties.

The project could be called `Crosscutting` or maybe `Resources` if you intend to have many, as it contains resources that are references by multiple projects within your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Luke said you can create a seperate class library project and add a resource file to it.
make that resource file's access identifier public so that it can be used in multiple project .
See in below image
[image: Change the access identifier section Internal to public]

Reference this class library project to your other projects where you want to use it.
It will work as you needed